# Getting "$ is not defined"

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, firefox, jgrowl

I am trying to explore a feature of adding growl notifications to the tests.
This enables the messages to be added on the screen while test execution.

I am trying this approach by following steps specified in : http://elementalselenium.com/tips/53-growl

Machine: windows 10
Selenium version : 2.53
Browser : Firefox 49

Below is script which i am using:

```
public class GrowlTest {

    static String JGROWL_SCRIPT = "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jgrowl/1.2.12/jquery.jgrowl.min.js";
    static String JQUERY_SCRIPT = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js";
    static String JGROWL_STYLE = "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jgrowl/1.2.12/jquery.jgrowl.min.css";
    static FirefoxDriver driver;
    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException
    {   


        driver =new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //waitForJStoLoad();

          driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
          growlNotification(driver,"hi this is inital test..", "try");
          driver.get("http://www.amazon.com");
          Thread.sleep(10000);
          System.out.println("waiting for popup to come..");
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Stay')]")).click();
          System.out.println("clicked on pop up..now waiting for notification...");
          Thread.sleep(10000);
          System.out.println("wait is completed..");

          growlNotification(driver,"Hi First try","first:");    
          Thread.sleep(2000);
          growlNotification(driver,"Hi second try","second:");
          Thread.sleep(2000);
          growlNotification(driver,"Hi third try","third:");
          Thread.sleep(2000);
          growlNotification(driver,"Hi fourth try","fourth:");
          Thread.sleep(2000);
          driver.quit();


        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
    private static void growlNotification(WebDriver driver, String msg, String header) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        FirefoxDriver js=(FirefoxDriver) driver;
        js.executeScript("if (!window.jQuery) {var jquery = document.createElement('script'); jquery.type = 'text/javascript';jquery.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jquery)}");
        //TODO Add check for existing jQuery on page
        js.executeScript( "var jq = document.createElement('script'); jq.type = 'text/javascript'; jq.src = '" +
        JQUERY_SCRIPT + "'; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);" );

        js.executeScript( "$.getScript(\"" + JGROWL_SCRIPT + "\");" );

        js.executeScript( "var lnk = document.createElement('link'); lnk.rel = 'stylesheet'; lnk.href = '" +
        JGROWL_STYLE + "'; lnk.type = 'text/css'; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(lnk);" );
        js.executeScript( "$.jGrowl('" + msg + "', { header: '" + header + "' });" );
    }
}
```

On executing this i get below error:

> waiting for popup to come.. clicked on pop up..now waiting for
>   notification... wait is completed.. Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: $.jGrowl is not a function
>   Command duration or timeout: 17 milliseconds Build info: version:
>   '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40' System
>   info: host: 'mkarthik-WX-1', ip: '192.168.0.106', os.name: 'Windows
>   10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_73'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   databaseEnabled=true, version=40.0, platform=WINDOWS,
>   nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox,
>   takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   8249259c-1211-4472-b52f-fc0471061816  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:577)
>     at com.tests.GrowlTest.growlNotification(GrowlTest.java:74)     at
>   com.tests.GrowlTest.main(GrowlTest.java:38) Caused by:
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: $.jGrowl is not a function
>   Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15
>   16:57:40' System info: host: 'mkarthik-WX-1', ip: '192.168.0.106',
>   os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_73'

However, the same script works when i execute the below code :

```
package com.tests;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import com.google.common.base.Predicate;

    public class GrowlTest {

        static String JGROWL_SCRIPT = "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jgrowl/1.2.12/jquery.jgrowl.min.js";
        static String JQUERY_SCRIPT = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js";
        static String JGROWL_STYLE = "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jgrowl/1.2.12/jquery.jgrowl.min.css";
        static FirefoxDriver driver;
        public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException
        {   


            driver =new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            //waitForJStoLoad();

              driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
              growlNotification(driver,"hi this is inital test..", "try");
              driver.get("http://www.amazon.in");
              Thread.sleep(10000);
              System.out.println("waiting for popup to come..");
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Stay')]")).click();
              System.out.println("clicked on pop up..now waiting for notification...");
              Thread.sleep(10000);
              System.out.println("wait is completed..");

              growlNotification(driver,"Hi First try","first:");    
              Thread.sleep(2000);
              growlNotification(driver,"Hi second try","second:");
              Thread.sleep(2000);
              growlNotification(driver,"Hi third try","third:");
              Thread.sleep(2000);
              growlNotification(driver,"Hi fourth try","fourth:");
              Thread.sleep(2000);
              driver.quit();


            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
        private static void growlNotification(WebDriver driver, String msg, String header) throws InterruptedException 
        {
            FirefoxDriver js=(FirefoxDriver) driver;
            js.executeScript("if (!window.jQuery) {var jquery = document.createElement('script'); jquery.type = 'text/javascript';jquery.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jquery)}");
            //TODO Add check for existing jQuery on page
            js.executeScript( "var jq = document.createElement('script'); jq.type = 'text/javascript'; jq.src = '" +
            JQUERY_SCRIPT + "'; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);" );

            js.executeScript( "$.getScript(\"" + JGROWL_SCRIPT + "\");" );

            js.executeScript( "var lnk = document.createElement('link'); lnk.rel = 'stylesheet'; lnk.href = '" +
            JGROWL_STYLE + "'; lnk.type = 'text/css'; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(lnk);" );
            js.executeScript( "$.jGrowl('" + msg + "', { header: '" + header + "' });" );
        }
    }
```

Kindly help and suggest what needs to be done.

Thanks and regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that you need to sleep for a bit in-between js.executeScript() calls to give the javascript that you are calling time to load.  If you look, the script you say works has a variety of sleep's between operations, likely to allow for things to load and process.

Comment: Nope...tried with the same code..it doesnt work getting the same error : Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: $.jGrowl is not a function
Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'

Comment: i have added the required files 1)<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 2)<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jgrowl/1.2.12/jquery.jgrowl.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 3)<link type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jgrowl/1.2.12/jquery.jgrowl.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> It works fine when i try $.jGrowl('hi') in console. But when executed through java program i get "$ is not defined"  @stanlemon